# Strip Characters Before Period If Filename Has Prefix in Bash

Tags: bash, sed, rename

I have a directory that looks like this:

```
pages/
    folder1/
        folder1.filename1.txt
        folder1.filename2.txt
    folder2/
        folder2.filename4.txt
        folder2.filename5.txt
    folder3/
        filename6.txt
```

I want it to look like this:

```
pages/
    folder1/
        filename1.txt
        filename2.txt
    folder2/
        filename3.txt
        filename4.txt
    folder3/
        filename5.txt
```

With `ls * | sed -e s/^[^.]*.// > /tmp/filenames.txt` I get a file containing:

```
filename1.txt
filename2.txt
filename3.txt
filename4.txt
txt
```

**How can I tell sed to** ignore filenames of the form `[filename].[suffix]` and only look at filenames of the form `[foldername].[filename].[suffix]`?

The final script (as pointed out, the find command would simplify things, but this worked):

```
for folder in $(ls .)
do
    if test -d $folder
    then
        pushd $folder
                ls * | sed 's/.*\.\(.*\..*\)/\1/' > /tmp/filenames.txt
                ls * > /tmp/current.txt

                exec 3</tmp/current.txt
                exec 4</tmp/filenames.txt

                while read file <&3; read name <&4;
                do
                    mv "$file" "$name"
                done

                rm /tmp/current.txt
                rm /tmp/filenames.txt
        popd
    else
        echo $folder "not a directory"
    fi
done

exit 0
```

**This page is now a community wiki.** You can add more elegant solutions below:

```
for folder in $(ls .)
do 
     something better
```

Comment: You probably have/want a `pushd` somewhere in there.

Comment: Also you want precisely "${folder}." prefix removed, or the first section of any three block (dot-separated) filename?

Comment: @Douglas oops, accidentally removed the pushd. I put it back in. Yes, that's precisely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
sed 's/.*\.\(.*\..*\)/\1/'
```

You should really use `find` then you wouldn't need the check for "-d folder" or the temp file and execs or the while loop.

You can avoid the temporary file by using process substition:

```
while read line
do
    echo $line
done < <(ls)
```

Another item of interest: your system may already have a Perl script called `rename` or `prename` which will rename files using a regular expression.

Comment: That did the trick. I look into using find next time I have to do something like this. Not knowing regexp is an annoying hinderance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `sed`:

```
ls * > /tmp/current.txt
exec 3</tmp/current.txt
while read file <&3;
do
    replacement=${file#${folder}.}
    if [ "$replacement" != "txt" ] ; then
        mv "$file" "$replacement"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Will gives this a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, the issue with this method is that there are some cases where I have this: Folder1/Folder1.txt. This method renames those files "txt".

Comment: You said you wanted to remove "Folder1." prefix :-).

Answer (score 0):

use the following regex:

```
/\A(.\*?\\.){2,2}.+\Z/
```

Comment: Er, throws a syntax error. I don't know enough about regular expressions to know how to fix it.

Comment: replace \A by ^ and \Z by $ and try again